# Can we use $(this) with other selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

For ex.:

```
$("#"+$(this).attr("id")+" option[value='0']")
```

Can we reduce the code to something like

```
$(this+" option[value='0']")
```

Answer (score 15):

These will do the same as your first statement: find the `option` elements having `0` as their `value` and being the (not restrictively direct) child of `this`.

```
$(this).find('option[value="0"]')
```

or

```
$('option[value="0"]', this)
```

**Resources:**

- [jQuery .find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [Understanding context in jQuery](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/24/understanding-the-context-in-jquery)
- [jsFiddle Illustration](http://jsfiddle.net/ebpWf/)